# GetGenericArguments()[0] vs GetGenericArguments()[1] in regards to anonymous types in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection

**The Goal**

I need a list view that can display any query I throw into it without having to create a custom view model or custom view.

**The Solution**

Using reflection, I can pass anonymous types to custom helper functions to create all headers and rows within a table.

**The Problem**

In order to get the anonymous type, I need to use the `GetGenericArguments()` method and use the `[]` operator to pull that info out.  However, when I use a named `Type` (a model that I have hard-coded), the necessary index to grab that type from the `IEnumerable<object>` line is 0.  When I use an anonymous type, the necessary index is 1.  Why is this, and is there a better way I can get that `Type`?

**The Code**

Controller:

(I can pass any of these model queries to the view and the table displays accordingly)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var models = taskService.ReadMany().Select(m => new
    {
        Name = m.Title,
        Summary = m.Details,
        Importance = m.Priority,
        DueDate = m.DateDue
    });
    var models = taskService.ReadMany();
    var models = taskService.ReadMany().GroupBy(m => new { m.DateDue }).Select(m => new { NumberOfProjects = m.Count(), DueOn = m.Key.DateDue });
    return View(models);
}
```

Helper Extensions:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString BuildHeaders(this HtmlHelper html, Type type)
    {
        var tr = new TagBuilder("tr");
        var model = type;
        foreach (MemberInfo prop in model.GetProperties())
        {
            var th = new TagBuilder("th");
            var display = prop.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute)) as DisplayAttribute;
            if (display != null) th.InnerHtml = display.Name;
            else if (!prop.Name.Contains("Id")) th.InnerHtml = prop.Name;
            else continue;
            tr.InnerHtml += th.ToString();
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tr.ToString());
    }
    public static MvcHtmlString BuildRow(this HtmlHelper html, object model)
    {
        var tr = new TagBuilder("tr");
        var type = model.GetType();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in type.GetProperties())
        {
            var td = new TagBuilder("td");
            var val = prop.GetValue(model, null);
            string valString = "";
            if (val != null) valString = val.ToString();
            if (!prop.Name.Contains("Id")) td.InnerHtml = valString;
            else continue;
            tr.InnerHtml += td.ToString();
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tr.ToString());
    }
```

List View:

```
@model IEnumerable<object>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Type type = Model.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[1]; //this line if I'm using an anonymous type
    Type type = Model.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]; //this line if I'm using a named type.  I need to make this line handle both situations without manual intervention

}
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    @Html.BuildHeaders(type)

@foreach (object item in Model) {
    @Html.BuildRow(item)
}
</table>
```

Comment: Your `Type type = ....` lines of code should not be in the view. Your extension method should just be accepting the model (and you get the `type` in the extension method) and building the complete table header and rows

Comment: @StephenMuecke You're right, I still need to refactor after I get it all working the way I would like.  But that still leaves me in a place of trying to determine at runtime which index to use, doesn't it?

Comment: Can't you just use a ternary conditioned on `IsConstructedGenericType`?

Comment: @Comintern I don't think so, as that would require that I have the type to begin with, right?  I suppose I could test the length of the array returned from `GetGenericArguments()` call to prevent an `IndexOutOfRangeException` but that seems a bit inelegant

Comment: What does `Model.GetType().IsConstructedGenericType` return for each case?

Comment: @Comintern it returns true in both cases (the model is always an `IEnumerable` of some sort in that test as well).  When I run it on the `GetGenericArguments()[]` lines, I get true in the correct scenario, but an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when using an anonymous type

Comment: You could use  `Type type = Model.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Last();`, but then that does not take into account passing an array of objects, so you should also be testing if `Model.GetType().IsGenericType` and `Model.GetType().IsGenericType.IsArray` (in which case you use `.GetElementType()`)

Comment: However passing an anonymous type is not a good idea, and you should always be  creating a view model to represent what you want in the view, which has multiple other benefits including being able to make use of `ModelMetadata` to generate your html (including the `DisplayName` and formatted model value based on attributes)

Comment: I think you're chasing off down the wrong path. Even if you get this code working with anonymous types, it's still not going to let you "display any query I throw into it". Anonymous types are still *types* that the compiler has to specifically create.

Comment: You might be interested in [mvc-tablehelper](https://github.com/stephenmuecke/mvc-tablehelper) - which includes 2 methods - `TableDisplayFor()` and `TableEditorFor()` which generates tables for a collection. Unfortunately I have not written the documentation yet, but I did write about an earlier version of that code in [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774228/MVC-Html-Table-Helper-Part-Display-Tables)

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.  @Damien_The_Unbeliever The broader goal of what I'm wanting to accomplish is basically a reporting tool in which I don't have to do much more than write the linq/lambda queries to create a new report.  **StephenMuecke** I agree 100% with your thoughts on attribute usage and the benefits of view models.  My only issue is that let's say I have 100 reports.  If each report requires a distinct view model and razor view, this would be a nightmare to manage.  I will definitely take a look at your mvc-tablehelper, thank you for that!

Comment: @TylerSells, If you have 100 distinct reports then you should have 100 view models representing those reports, although I suspect you could make use of inheritance (with base view models for common properties) to minimize the code.

Comment: As for the views, surely you would want additional information such as the report title etc in the view, but you could possibly just use one view by using a parent model containing properties for the report title etc and an `IEnumerable<object> Details` property for generating the table (where you set `Details = IEnumerable<SomeViewModel> in the GET method). But then you still have the problem of styling column widths etc for each specific table, so having a view for each report seems appropriate so you can include specific css files etc